# Magento 2 - RequireJS config file not importing JS files, no error thrown

Tags: javascript, magento, requirejs

In my `requirejs-config.js` file placed under `[MyModule]/view/frontend`, I include all my JS files like this:

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        "jquery.min": "MyVend_MyModule/js/jquery.min",
        "bootstrap": "MyVend_MyModule/js/bootstrap.min",
        "bootstrap-datepicker": "MyVend_MyModule/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min",
        "bootstrap-select": "MyVend_MyModule/js/bootstrap-select.min",
        "jquery.smoothState": "MyVend_MyModule/js/jquery.smoothState",
        "moment": "MyVend_MyModule/js/moment.min",
        ...
    },
    shim: {
        // 'libname' : ['dependency']
        "bootstrap": [ "jquery"],
        "bootstrap-datepicker": [ "jquery"],
        "bootstrap-select": [ "jquery"],
        "jquery.smoothState": [ "jquery"],
        "moment": [ "jquery"],
        ...
    }
};
```

My JS files are placed under `[MyModule]/view/frontend/web/js` and the file names match up, I can assure you.

Okay, so I do `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and such. The files are mirrored to `/pub/static/...` so I know they are there. When I refresh the page, the `requirejs-config.js` under `/pub/static/_requirejs/...` includes the content of my config file, so I know that is there as well. However, the javascript isn't being imported into the page, and I can confirm this by refreshing while looking at the Network tab (I am using Chrome). All it imports are the CSS files, which I declare under my layout xml files by:

```
<css src="MyVend_MyModule::css/bootstrap-select.min.css"/>
<css src="MyVend_MyModule::css/animate.min.css"/>
<css src="MyVend_MyModule::css/famfamfam-flags.css"/>
<css src="MyVend_MyModule::css/magnific-popup.css"/>
...
```

Those get imported correctly and they are there on the page. However, my JS files are not being imported, even though the files are there under `/pub/static` and it's in the `requirejs-config.js` file. Is there something I'm doing wrong? There is no error, which confuses me even more.

**I will be posting this on Magento SE as well, please do not mark as duplicate.**

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest you to use your code like bellow in requirejs-config file.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            moment: 'MyVend_MyModule/js/moment'
        }
    }
};
```

I'm not sure you can use minified files here or not. But there is an option in Admin to minify all the JS and CSS files at the end.

Comment: I changed my code to be like yours. It still does not work.